# Protect backend from multiple form submits in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to protect my backend from multiple post requests to avoid duplicate data on the database and the server overload.

I've already blocked the frontend disabling the submit button after a first click, but it will not prevent some "smart user" to submit my form from the console or disable javascript from the page and try something.

So I want to know if Laravel has some solution for this case.

PS: I've already tried some solutions on the backend too if you want I can post here.

**As requested:**

So one of my alternatives is check if the incoming data is already on the database and denied the request if is it, it will prevent the duplicate data but not the server overload.

Another alternative is to create a token in session for one use only on Create() method from the controller, send the token to the view and put it on a hidden field, retrieve it from post request and check the post token with the session token. If the two tokens are the same, then unset it to avoid others requests try using it and if they try I deny the request.

Comment: Yes, post your backend solutions.

Comment: Have your already tried to save the ID of the new database entry in the session and update that entry on later submits?

Comment: @SandOfVega, posted as requested.

Comment: @PhilippMaurer I haven't tried it, but I've tried another similar solution and didn't work, because if the users requests are too fast, they could duplicate the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know who your users are (because they have an ID) then this is somewhat easy to do. Possibly use some sort of quick-access system such as Reddis to check-in that a user is in a state of edit while the action is being carried out.

*However* that creates complications of its own. Also doesn’t work if you don’t know who your users are.

The safer thing would be to make sure that your requests can handle potential problems. Consider using database transactions to ensure the integrity of the data.

It would depend really on what you’re trying to avoid, why you are, and what kind of data you’re worried about duplicating.

Answer (score 0):

if it's too important for you to protect for multiple submit u can put a random string in hidden input in your form and also put it in a special session for each form you have and check it every time and after that try to change your session after each time you end your proccess